# how to change autolayout constraints

Tags: ios, autolayout

I came across a problem related to autolayout. say I create view1 and view2, and view2 is a subview of view1. I create the right,left,top,bottom constraints between them.

Then, as the content in the view2 increasing, the height of view2 have to increase too. The height of view1 should increase to keep the bottom constraint between then.

So, what should I do now? increase the frame height of both to show the new content and keeping constraints at the same time?

I think I still not understant autoLayout and the frame well, can anyone give me some advise, thanks.

UPDATE:

***Actully View2 is an UICollectionView and I want to increase the height of it to show all the cells without scrolling. So as the datas grow, I have to increase the size of View2.***

Comment: What will increase the size of View2?

Comment: so long as there is no constraints at the bottom of view1 keeping its size fixed, then view2 should be able to push view1 down so long as view2's content does correctly make view2 resize properly

Comment: @Mr.UB  actully View2 is an UICollectionView and I want to increase the height of it to show all the cells without scrolling. So as the datas grow, I have to increase the size of View2.

Comment: @Fonix there is a constraint at the bottom of view1 whcih I did not mention, otherwise the IB will report an error related to AutoLayout.

Comment: yeah, what you could try is making that bottom constraints priority very low, so that view2's constraints have a higher priority than the bottom one of view1, making it stretch out instead of having the bottom of view1 in a fixed position

Comment: Please show some screenshot of your storyboard with constraints shown and views selected.

Comment: I agree with @Fonix , set the priority of the View1 bottom constraint to 750.

Comment: I have reset the priority as you said. Now I begin to change the height of view2. If I make a height constraint to view2 whose value is higher than the frame height now, view2 will get longer and view1 will grow according to the bottom constraint between them, everything works fine. But If I change the frame of view2 directly, there will be no change for view1. Does that mean I can only change the height by the way of making constraint but not changing frame.

Comment: collection view height cannot be changed according to the cells in it, you have to do some programming stuff, not only autolayouts.

Answer (score 0):

In order to increase the height of view1 when view2's height increases, first you can give 0 Leading, Top, Trailing, Bottom constraints to view2 that is inside view1, and a height constraint to view2 but not to view1, so when the height of view2 increases the height of view1 will be increased as well.